# Temporarily drop sf object geometry and restore it after dplyr manipulation without losing point geometry

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, geospatial, r-sf

I've sf point data for buildings with the following properties:

```
class(df)
"sf" "grouped_df" "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"
```

I used `st_drop_geometry` function in sf package to manipulate it using dplyr:

```
new_df <- st_drop_geometry(df) 
class(new_df)
"grouped_df" "tbl_df" "tbl" "data.frame"
```

How can I go back to restore my point geometry in the original dataset `df` after manipulation with dplyr?

Comment: The operation you describe seems at a first glance risky: what operation you need to perform that would be a problem on a spatial dataset? What is the point of dropping the geometry? If the manipulation with dplyr does not produce results as intended on a spatial data object there may be a perfectly valid reason for it (and you may need to rethink your approach). Having said that my suggestion would be to have unique id for the original dataset rows, and do a left or inner style join of mungled data back to it, using the unique id's as key.

Comment: sf already has methods for dplyr, I wonder what manipulation you need that isn’t supported and forces you to follow this (intended) approach.

Comment: What I mean is that you should be able to manipulate sf with dplyr seamlessly, so you won’t generally need to do any special treatment like that

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to completely get rid of your geometry. You can use st_drop_geometry() inside your dplyr pipe to do it momentarily. Here's an example of a simple dplyr operation:

```
sf_df %>% 
st_drop_geometry() %>%
  group_by(groupingVariable) %>% 
  count()
```

In this way, you'll still keep the geometry of your spatial dataframe.